# Why isn't Pickle calling __new__ like the documentation says?

Tags: python, deserialization, instance, pickle

The [documentation for Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) specifically says:

> Instances of a new-style class C are created using:
>
> ```
> obj = C.__new__(C, *args)
> ```

Attempting to take advantage of this, I created a singleton with no instance attributes or methods:

```
class ZeroResultSentinel(object):
    instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = super(ZeroResultSentinel, cls).__new__(cls, *args)
        return cls.instance
```

(This class is used in a caching layer to differentiate a no-result result from nothing in the cache.)

The singleton works great (every call to `ZeroResultSentinel()` results in the same instance in memory, and `ZeroResultSentinel() == ZeroResultSentinel()` evaluates to `True`). And I *can* pickle and unpickle the instance without errors. However, when I unpickle it, I get a different instance. So I placed a breakpoint within `__new__`. I hit the breakpoint every time I call `ZeroResultSentinel()`, but I do not hit a breakpoint when I unpickle a pickled `ZeroResultSentinel`. This is in direct contradiction to the documentation. So am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: What pickle protocol are you specifying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation doesn't really make it clear, but your `__new__` method will only be used for pickle protocol 2 and up:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __new__(cls):
...         print "New"
...         return object.__new__(cls)
...
>>> foo = Foo()
New
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(foo, protocol=0))
<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000025E9A20>
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(foo, protocol=2))
New
<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000022A3F60>
```

On Python 2, the default protocol is 0, so if you're using the default, you'll have to change that.

Comment: Well, shucks. I've confirmed that fixes it. But we're on a very old version of Django that doesn't specify the protocol for the cache backend, so there's nothing I can do about it until we upgrade. How _does_ Pickle create an instance in earlier protocols if not using `__new__`?

Comment: Correction: This has nothing to do with Django. We're just at the mercy of a cache library that does the pickling without specifying a protocol

Comment: I was able to add `'pickleProtocol': pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,` to the configuration settings for our cache backend to get this to work. Thanks so much for the help! (I'm still curious, if you have a minute, _how_ Pickle can create an instance of an object without calling `__new__`.)

Comment: @NickWilliams: It uses *a* `__new__` method, just not yours. Specifically, it's the `__new__` method of the first class in the MRO written in C. That's usually `object.__new__`. [`copy_reg._reduce_ex`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/copy_reg.py#l57) does the bulk of the work for new-style class instance pickling in protocols 0 and 1; you can read its code for details.

Comment: The `_reconstructor` and `args` returned by `copy_reg._reduce_ex` are used for initial creation of the unpickled object as `_reconstructor(*args)`.